# Model-Free Implied Volatility: Data of Expired Options and Bond Price

Tags: fixed-income, implied-volatility, bloomberg, index, european-options

I am attempting to calculate Model-Free Implied Volatility for several equity indices (S&P500, NASDAQ100, CAC40, FTSE100, DJIA, EUROSTOXX50, NIKKEI225, NIFTY50). I wish to get historical data of expired options since Jan 2000. Can I obtain this data from bloomberg in some way?

Another question I have is that I am supposed to use the price of an appropriate bond for each index. Ideally I would like to use 3m or 6m LIBOR rates corresponding to each country. However, if you could suggest any particular bond (like government bonds) whose daily price is readily available on bloomberg, I would be thankful to you.

Kind Regards,
Vishal

Comment: Welcome to the QSE. When you say 'model-free implied volatility', what do you mean by this exactly? Can you give a reference?

Comment: http://pbfea2005.rutgers.edu/2007/Papers/095-the%20forecasting%20performance.pdf

Comment: It's been a while I used BBG, but you can download historical I V data by moneyness and tenor and also LIBOR3M data. How much data and how far back you can go might depend on your data plan with BBG.

Answer (score 0):

With BBG, you can use OPT_CHAIN (on FLDS - hence Excel) using SINGLE_DATE_OVERRIDE with a date in the past in YYYYMMDD format to get tickers back until 2012.

2000 is generally possible, but not systematically via API. If you want to get historical option chain before Feb 2012, you have to to make educated guesses for the the ticker. As a workaround, in case you don't know the ticker syntax, you can use OVME BT (backtest) in listed mode, to get the tickers historically. Generally, this is better to be asked at the help desk.

Your major problem however, is that getting just the current chain for SPX only, and loading a few data points like current price, and open interest, will blow your standard desktop subscription data limit already (meaning your API will freeze and not work anymore).

I recommend you talk to your market data team before attempting to download such a huge amount of data.

Libor rates are no problem. You can use ICVS and get the data for this curves conveniently into excel as well. This is also not much data and shouldn't pose a problem with your license.

**Edit**: I read the paper and realized that Model Free is a bit of a misnomer because they used Black Scholes to construct a VOL surface which they use to back out option prices that they use to compute "model free" IV.

You can find IVOL on OVDV (not built with cubic spline but mixed lognormal and substantial filtering algos to address the issues why the authors also don't use actual option prices - see white paper on the help page). This so called BVOL surface is premium data in any case and cannot be downloaded without an additional data license.

Comment: When you put it like that, it appears that the approach is not model-free after all. However, the Black-Scholes Model is only utilized in the data preparation phase and the eventual calculation of MFIV is not based on any parametric assumption. 

In addition, I have a question related to the flat extrapolation prescribed in their approach. It is not practically feasible to extend the range of strikes beyond a certain number due to memory constraints. One approach I am considering is to add n rows below and above the existing range of strikes (n could be 5 or 10, for example). Please suggest